# Google cloud function crashes during testing even though the deployment is fine

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I built a cloud function (a very simple function - not very efficient). Below is the code and screenshot-

```py
import functions_framework
import requests
@functions_framework.http
def hello():
    URL='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=36&lon=139&appid=a70f3b4f60b2f4c64e7aad63df5758d7'
    r = requests.get(url = URL)
    data = r.json()
    b={}
    b['temp']=data['main']['temp']
    b['pressure']=data['main']['pressure']
    return b
print(hello())
```

[Delopyment code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fe9u7.png)

I am trying to get the temperature and pressure for a location. The log is attached below and values are being fetched -
[log file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H6F6.png)

However, there is an error called "hello() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given" which I am unable to fix.

Could someone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Functions will be executed under events and in your case an HTTP event. The registered function (in this case `hello`) will always receive an argument which is the HTTP request done to the function.

In fact this is very clear in the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/write-http-functions#http-example-python):

> In Python, you register an HTTP handler function with the Functions Framework for Python. Your HTTP handler function must accept a Flask request object as an argument and return a value that Flask can convert into an HTTP response object.

The code could be:

```py
import functions_framework
import requests

@functions_framework.http
def hello(request):
    URL='https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=36&lon=139&appid=a70f3b4f60b2f4c64e7aad63df5758d7'
    r = requests.get(url = URL)
    data = r.json()
    b={}
    b['temp']=data['main']['temp']
    b['pressure']=data['main']['pressure']
    return b
```

I'd highly recommend to first read the docs  since it seems you've not understood Cloud Functions completely. Basically Cloud Functions work as a very tiny web app.

As well I don't recommend to print the result. The point of using an HTTP Cloud Function is to get an HTTP response and not going to the logs every time to view that.

Finally the fact that the build is ok does not mean the function at runtime will work as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the your response, Ferregina.

The code shared by you works perfectly for me. I am new to GCP and will go through the documentation.

Also, the reason for using "print" statement in the function was only for testing - while using cloud scheduler, I do not intend to have this statement.

Answer (score 0):

Declare hello like this:

```
def hello(request):
```

This also means you **cannot** call the function like this:

```
print(hello())
```

The Python decorator `@functions_framework.http` defines the functions's signature.